# Question about normal module.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and let $\phi: S\to R=S/I$ be $k$-algebras. Then given a homomorphism $\varphi: I\to R$, it's said that it induces a homomorphism $\psi:I/I^2\to R$ since $\varphi$ kills $I^2$.

I am not sure about this: if $\varphi(x)$ is nontrivial in $R$, then $\varphi(x^2)=\varphi(x)^2$ can be nontrivial in $R=S/I$, right? Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\varphi(x^2) = x\varphi(x)$. One possible point of confusion: why does $\varphi(x) = x\varphi(1)$ not hold?

Comment: So, it's not a ring homomorphsim, but more like a morphism of modules?

Comment: If you require rings to have a $1$, then $I$ isn't even a ring. Even if you don't require this, I believe it is meant to be a module homomorphism.